# large mysql database slow acctions

Tags: php, mysql

i have a database like this

[image]

it have content of a site i grabbed with a php script and linux cron jobs

after i got all pages of the sites it goes to work slowly

and server load is:
[image]

now i cant run a small query like this

```
SELECT * FROM `content` WHERE `html` LIKE '%%simple%%'
```

i think 3gb is not to much for mysql!
the server have dual 5620 cpu with 32 g of ram
with this hardware i think ed it can handle up to 2tb of db!!

UPDATE 1 :
my content table is like this
[image]

i have one index and its the id but a query like this need a lot of time to run too

```
 <?php echo mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages where `update_date`!='0000-00-00 00:00:00' and `type`='page';")); ?>
```

you mean i just change the `html` field to full text!?

Comment: you will need to add FULL TEXT indexes to your tables, and you want to switch to MyISAM, and use MATCH.

Comment: @ChristopherMorrissey An index alone likely won't solve the problem as having a leading wildcard in the LIKE will disallow proper use of indexes.  What OP needs to look into is a full text search - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html He also needs to convert tables to MyISAM in order to utilize such a search and provide a FULLTEXT index on the fields within which searches will be performed.

Comment: I'm shocked noone has made you run an `EXPLAIN` yet....

Comment: Based on your update you will want to add indexes to `update_date` and `type`, and @MikeB is right about looking at `EXPLAIN` ... but I would start by reading up on Indexes http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html

Comment: @ChristopherMorrissey `type`  and `update_date` are for different table and for the `content` table if i add full text it dont need more time on inserts!?

Comment: however when i tried to add full text index to html field i got this error: ` #1214 - The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes`

Comment: you need to switch the table type to `MyISAM`

Comment: it was `myisam` but i switch to `innodb` for performance!!!

Answer (score 4):

Using `LIKE` as you are with wildcards on both sides does not allow MySQL to utilize an index (if the field is indexed) so 3GB of database to slog through would actually take quite a while. I would recommend removing the left hand wildcards and (potentially) taking a look at `MATCH AGAINST` using a `FULLTEXT` index.

For more:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html

It is worth noting that in MySQL **PRIOR** to version 5.6 you will need to convert your table to MyISAM to utilize the `FULLTEXT` engine.  In 5.6 and up you can use them in InnoDB as well as MyISAM.  If for some reason you can't upgrade or use 5.6+, then you could always setup a MyISAM table with only the information you need to have stored for `FULLTEXT` purposes. Then setup triggers to duplicate/remove information from the MyISAM table as it gets deleted from the InnoDB.  This may not work within your project goals, but it is one solution.

Comment: You might add that OP would need to utilize MyISAM table and provide FULLTEXT index on the searched fields.

Comment: i added some details to my question

Comment: @MikeBrant According to the manual, as of MySQL 5.6 `FULLTEXT` indexes are now available to InnoDB's as well.  Good point nonetheless; I will add it to my answer.

Comment: thank you guys , but i need your idea,if i change the engine and add full text and other indexes ,,and with these hardware,2*5620 and 32 gb ram how much size of db it can handle!? for example in can do 5tb!?

Comment: @peimanF Without understanding your entire system, the size of the data that needs to be indexed, etc. there is no way for use to tell you what your hardware can handle.  For optimum performance, you would want to keep your entire index in memory (so you need to know the index size).  So you likely need to do some testign on your own to understand your hardware needs.  I would however say that if you are talking about needing to index 5TB worth of data for search, then MySQL is likely not your best choice. You would need to look into technologies like Solr, Hadoop, etc. to better scale.

Answer (score 1):

Every time that query runs you're searching through *3 billion* characters for a string match.

[You need to use an index](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/like-performance-tuning).

I also think you're using the wrong query predicate and should use a [full-text-search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) which is designed for this sort of thing. You also want to index the full-text-search.

Comment: An index is not necessarily going to help this sort of wildcard search. He probably needs to look into full text searching  as noted by Crackertastic in this case.

Comment: i added some details to my question

Comment: @MikeBrant Oh good point, he's got a wildcard at the start of the word so it can't be indexed with a b-tree like you would normally do. Full text searches have a different type of index but I'm more familiar with what postgres does around things like GIN indexes.